# What is the proper way to try / except a timeout in Python

Tags: python

After a server upgrade, I'm having an issue with a python script eating up all the server connections because it appears that after a timeout it doesn't actually end the loop.   The code looks like:

```
if os.name == 'posix':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
    signal.alarm(__TIMEOUT__)
try:
    self.inputline = self.rfile.readline()
except IOError:
    continue
if os.name == 'posix':
    signal.alarm(0)
```

The signal occurs and all that does is set a `terminated` variable to 1 and print a log about the time out.  The while looks like `while not self.terminated:`.  My guess is that because it has `except IOError:` the except doesn't occur and it's still sitting on the `readline()`.   So the question is, what is the proper way to ensure the `SIGALRM` will cause the `continue` which will end the loop and exit the script?

TIA!!

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: `continue` does _not_ end the loop. It _continues_ it. You are looking for `break`.

Comment: right but the loop is controlled by the variable the alarm signal sets so only on a timeout the loop ends.

Comment: where's the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handle_timeout()` you can raise an exception to get your `try` to wake up.  Then catch that exception in your try/except:

```
def handle_timeout(signum, frame):
    raise KeyboardInterrupt('received signal to exit')

while not terminated:
    try:
        self.inputline = self.rfile.readline()
    except IOError, KeyboardInterrupt:
        terminated = True
        continue
```

Comment: Also, if you are setting `terminated = True` in your signal handler function, you need to declare it `global`